# Phase of Trig Functions - Is it different to phase shift?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

[Phase Trig Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWmFe.png)

I am really confused with the phase of a trig function because for example in $8d$ question iv the answer is $π/4$ but wouldn't it be $-π/4$ because it's shifting to the left?
Or is that phase shift, are phase and phase shift different?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "phase" vs "phase shift" is the sort of "niche" terminology that changes easily from author to author. So we cannot clarify what your particular author may have meant here. Personally, I am with you. The answer should be $-\frac \pi4$.